# Why does it echo all the errors in the file

Tags: php

For some reason, it displays all the errors when the no image is uploaded. Is there away to allow on 1 error to display depending on the error.

Thanks

```
<?php

require 'header.php';

?>

<center>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You could store all your errors (in maybe an array) and selectively display them at the end or you could use `die("OH SNAP");` to display your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas...

- One option that you have is to add an [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) statement after each
  error. So the first encountered will be shown, and the script will
  exit.
- Another option is to store all the errors in a variable and print it 
  at the end of the script. All the errors will be shown.
- Finally what you can do is to refactor your code and have some nested condition statements and allow them to only have one error at a time.